# How to extract header information via CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libcurl

I want to extract header information by using the CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION in my c++ program.

[How can I use CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION to read a single response header field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516773/how-can-i-use-curlopt-headerfunction-to-read-a-single-response-header-field) provides the solution on how to get those header information but I want to know why my code is not working and a possible solution with example.

```
//readHeader function which returns the specific header information

size_t readHeader(char* header, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata) {
Erza oprations; //class which contains string function like startsWith etc
if (oprations.startsWith(header, "Content-Length:")) {
    std::string header_in_string = oprations.replaceAll(header, "Content-Length:", "");
    long size = atol(header_in_string.c_str());
    file_size = size; // file_size is global variable
    std::cout << size; // here it is showing correct file size
}
else if (oprations.startsWith(header, "Content-Type:")) {
 // do something 
}else
 // do something
return size * nitems;
}
// part of main function
curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(path, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "./ca-bundle.crt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, readHeader);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

fclose(fp);
std::cout << file_size; // showing value 0
```

Getting correct file size in readHeader function but getting 0 bytes in main function.

Comment: At the end of the shown code, it should be `std::cout << file_size` ? or `size` is also another global variable ?

Comment: its file_size, I have edited that.

Comment: it's hard to say where is the problem, but if the `readHeader()` catch the correct value and at the end, the value was changed, there may be a bug in the program, that the `file_size` memory was overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in your github depot, `oprations` (operations !?) is a local variable, and will be released at the end of the readHeader function. A way to process the readHeader function and get the correct file size for a given Erza instance is to pass its pointer to `userdata` value. The Erza class may be rewritten as :

```
class Erza : public Endeavour {

    //... your class body 

public: 
    bool download (const char *url,const char* path){
            curl = curl_easy_init();
            if (curl) {
                fp = fopen(path, "wb");
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "./ca-bundle.crt");
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, readHeader);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, this ); //<-- set this pointer to userdata value used in the callback.

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
                fclose(fp);
                return false;
            }else
                return true;

        }

    size_t analyseHeader( char* header, size_t size, size_t nitems ){

        if (startsWith(header, "Content-Length:")) {
            std::string header_in_string = replaceAll(header, "Content-Length:", "");
            long size = atol(header_in_string.c_str());
            file_size = size; // file_size is a member variable 
            std::cout << size; // here it is showing correct file size
        }
        else if (startsWith(header, "Content-Type:")) {
         // do something 
        }else
         // do something
        return size * nitems;
    }   

}//Eof class Erza

size_t readHeader(char* header, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata) {

    //get the called context (Erza instance pointer set in userdata)

    Erza * oprations = (Erza *)userdata; 
    return oprations->analyseHeader( header, size, nitems );
}
```

Comment: the return type of analyseHeader will be size_t, everything else is perfect